# Scrapy : Why should I use yield for multiple request?

Tags: request, scrapy, yield, sequential

Simply I need three conditions.

1) Log-in
2) Multiple request
3) Synchronous request ( sequential like 'C' )

I realized 'yield' should be used for multiple request.
But I think 'yield' works differently with 'C' and not sequential.
So I want to use request without 'yield' like below.
But crawl method wasn`t called ordinarily.
How can I call crawl method sequentially like C ?

```
class HotdaySpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = "hotday"
allowed_domains = ["test.com"]
login_page = "http://www.test.com"
start_urls = ["http://www.test.com"]

maxnum = 27982
runcnt = 10

def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,formname='login_form',formdata={'id': 'id', 'password': 'password'}, callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
    global maxnum
    global runcnt
    i = 0

    while i < runcnt :
        **Request(url="http://www.test.com/view.php?idx=" + str(maxnum) + "/",callback=self.crawl)**
        i = i + 1

def crawl(self, response):
    global maxnum
    filename = 'hotday.html'

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:            
    f.write(unicode(response.body.decode(response.encoding)).encode('utf-8'))
    maxnum = maxnum + 1
```

Comment: related (but not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

When you return a list of requests (that's what you do when you `yield` many of them) Scrapy will schedule them and you can't control the order in which the responses will come.

If you want to process one response at a time and in order, you would have to return only one request in your after_login method and construct the next request in your crawl method.

```
def after_login(self, response):
    return Request(url="http://www.test.com/view.php?idx=0/", callback=self.crawl)

def crawl(self, response):
    global maxnum
    global runcnt
    filename = 'hotday.html'

    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:            
    f.write(unicode(response.body.decode(response.encoding)).encode('utf-8'))
    maxnum = maxnum + 1
    next_page = int(re.search('\?idx=(\d*)', response.request.url).group(1)) + 1
    if < runcnt:
        return Request(url="http://www.test.com/view.php?idx=" + next_page + "/", callback=self.crawl)
```